# Topology of $TS^n$

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

I know that the tangent bundle $TS^n$ is not very often trivial, i.e. isomorphic to $S^n\times\mathbb{R}^n$. If it is not, is it still homeomorphic to $S^n\times\mathbb{R}^n$? It is clear that they are homotopy equivalent, but I am not too sure whether they are also homemorphic.

Comment: This is not easy. See [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/92337/21564) about the case $n = 2$.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese many thanks!

Answer (score -2):

The Euler class is a topological invariant and the Euler class of $S^2$ is $2$, so it is homeomorphic to the trivial bundle.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_class#Properties

Comment: I guess you mean to say not?

Comment: yes, it is not trivial in the topology category.

Comment: So how does your answer show that e.g. for $n=9$ there is no homeomorphism? you could only rule out even $n$ if your answer were correct